# React native init projects with old buildToolsVersion 23.0.3

Tags: android, react-native

I have react-native-cli v2.0.1 and react-native v0.55.4

When I create a new project with react-native init myProject, I see in android build.gradle file use buildToolsVersion "23.0.3" which brings me problems with the module react-native-fbsdk v0.7.0 that I need to install, it does not solve all the dependencies when I try react-native run-android

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3.

I have newest build tools versions installed
[image]

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 0):

Open your android folder with android studio and upgrade buildtools wen he ask to you and download the correct buildtools with the SDK manager. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `YourProject\android\app` find `build.gradle`. You can set `buildToolsVersion` there:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

...
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolve the problem, with only remove my `Expo` App in my phone and run `react-native run-android`, that install proper `Expo` version.

This is not the last publish in Play Store, which I installed and don't work.

Hope it helps.